# Verificar cor predominante e porcentagem de preenchimento da imagem

Tags: javascript

Em um projeto que estou trabalhando, surgiu a necessidade de verificar se é uma imagem *upload* é realmente válida ou uma imagem totalmente aleatória. A ideia seria verificar qual seria a cor predominante e qual seria a porcentagem desta cor de início. Um exemplo seria resgatar o RGB e retornar por exemplo que ela existe em cerca de 90% da imagem. Estava dando uma olhada nessa "*lib*" [Color Thief](https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/) em Javascript, porém não conseguir verificar a porcentagem da cor em predominância.

Qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isso?

```js
const $input = document.getElementById('input');
const $canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const $resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');

const ctx = $canvas.getContext("2d");
const reader = new FileReader();
const image = new Image();

const size = 200;

$input.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
 const input = event.target;
 if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
});

reader.onload = (event) => {
 image.src = event.target.result;
};

image.onload = () => {
  $canvas.width = size;
 $canvas.height = $canvas.width * (image.height / image.width);
 
 const oc = document.createElement('canvas');
 const octx = oc.getContext('2d');

 oc.width = $canvas.width;
 oc.height = $canvas.height;
 octx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, oc.width, oc.height);

 ctx.drawImage(oc, 0, 0, oc.width, oc.height, 0, 0, oc.width, oc.height);
 
    // hardcode value
 $resultado.innerHTML = 'resultado: 60% cor: #0B70A4' ;
};
```

```html
<main class="centerer">
 <input type="file" id="input"/><br/>
 <canvas id="canvas"></canvas><br/>
 <span id="resultado"></span>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sem Color Thief.

```js
const getMaxColorAndPercent = ( imageData ) =>
{
    const table = {};
    const colors = Array.prototype.slice.call( new Uint32Array( imageData.data.buffer ) );
    void  colors.forEach( color => table[color] = (table[color]|0) + 1 );

    const maxValue = Object.values( table ).reduce( ( a, b )  => Math.max( a, b ) );
    const maxColor = Object.keys( table ).find( color => table[color] == maxValue );

    const percent = maxValue / colors.length * 100;
    const hexRGBcolorResult = (
        ( maxColor       & 255 ) << 16 | 
        ( maxColor >>  8 & 255 ) <<  8 | 
          maxColor >> 16 & 255 
        )
        .toString( 16 )
        .padStart( 6, '0' )
        .toUpperCase( );
    /*
    const hexRGBAcolorResult = (
        ( maxColor       & 255 ) << 24 | 
        ( maxColor >>  8 & 255 ) << 16 | 
        ( maxColor >> 16 & 255 ) <<  8 | 
          maxColor >> 24 & 255
        )
        .toString( 16 )
        .padStart( 8, '0' )
        .toUpperCase( );
    */
    resultado.innerHTML = `resultado: ${ percent.toFixed( 3 ) }% cor: #${ hexRGBcolorResult }`;
    /**/ resultado.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    /**/ document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#' + hexRGBcolorResult;
}

const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = ( ) => 
{
    const image = new Image();
    image.onload = ( ) => 
    {
        const nW = canvas.width  = image.naturalWidth;
        const nH = canvas.height = image.naturalHeight;

        const ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
        ctx.drawImage( image, 0, 0 );
        const imageData = ctx.getImageData( 0, 0, nW, nH );

        getMaxColorAndPercent( imageData );

        const canvasvisualwidth  = 200;
        const canvasvisualheight = canvas.height = nH * (canvas.width = canvasvisualwidth) / nW;
        ctx.drawImage( image, 0, 0, canvasvisualwidth, canvasvisualheight );
    }

    image.src = reader.result;
}

input.onchange = ( ) => input.files[0] && reader.readAsDataURL( input.files[0] );
```

```html
<input type="file" id="input" accept="image/*"/><br/>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas><br/>
<span id="resultado"></span>
```